# Writing an array of structure objects to file & reading it

Tags: c, structure, file-handling

I have created an array of objects of a structure & I want to save it to a binary file. I then read the file again & populate the structure, however I am getting all the values as empty.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    long b;
}test;
int main(void) {
    test *o1;
    test *o2;
    int no_of_obj = 3,i;

    o1 = malloc(no_of_obj * sizeof(test));
    printf("fsdfsdf");
    o1[0].a = 11;
    o1[0].b = 12;
    o1[1].a = 21;
    o1[1].b = 22;
    o1[2].a = 31;
    o1[2].b = 32;

    for(i=0;i<no_of_obj;i++) {
        printf("%d %lu\n",o1[i].a,o1[i].b);
    }
    FILE *F = fopen("test.db","wb");

    for(i=0;i<no_of_obj;i++) {
        fwrite(&o1[i],sizeof(test),1,F);
    }
    fclose(F);
    printf("dfsdfds");
    F = fopen("test.db","rb");
    if(!F) {
        printf("no file!");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(F,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(F);
    int total_objects = size/sizeof(test);
    o2 = malloc(sizeof(test) * total_objects);

    for(i=0;i<total_objects;i++) {
        fread(&o2[i],sizeof(test),1,F);
    }
    for(i=0;i<total_objects;i++) {
        printf("%d %lu\n",o2[i].a,o2[i].b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need rewind() after fseek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [`fseek(F,0,SEEK_END);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) you are moving the position indicator to the end of the file. You need to move back to the start of the file before you call [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) (after you call [`ftell()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) to get the size) because it reads from the current position of the indicator.

You can do this with `fseek(F,0,SEEK_SET);` or [`rewind(F);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) - they have the same effect.

You would have noticed this sooner had you checked the return value of your `fread()`s as it returns the number of bytes successfully read. [`feof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feof) and [`ferror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ferror) are also important.

Comment: Thanks! How silly of me to forget about it. Next time will always remember to check number of bytes returned by fread!